# XMLSerializer not serializing DateTime

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Input...note that comment is generated code from the xsd tool. It's in a 31,834 line file and proprietary, but I put a rough approximation in here.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class comment
{
   private System.DateTime commentDateField;
   private bool commentDateFieldSpecified;
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   public System.DateTime commentDate
   { 
      get 
      {
         return this.commentDateField;
      }
      set
      {
         this.commentDateField = value;
      }  
   }
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
   public bool commentDateSpecified
   { 
      get 
      {
         return this.commentDateFieldSpecified;
      }
      set
      {
         this.commentDateFieldSpecified = value;
      }  
   }
   //other fields omitted for clarity
}
comment c = new comment();
c.text = txtComment.Text;
c.commentDate = DateTime.Now;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(comment));
xs.serialize(sw as TextWriter, c);
string output = sb.ToString();
```

output->

```
<comment>
  <text>My Comment Text</text>
</comment>
```

Where's the date?

Comment: Can we see the definition of your `Comment` class concerning those two properties?

Comment: We need to see the comment class definition.

Comment: Btw you are missing some using clauses

Comment: I can't copy/paste the code into here for various reasons, but I added some more context.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't even compile

Comment: The code as given does not compile. If adjusted to compile, it works as it should. You really have to post either the real code, or try to come up with the simplest _standalone_ (i.e. one can copy&paste it, compile, and run) example that _reproduces the problem_.

Comment: It doesn't compile because there is no class `XMLSerializer` (it's `XmlSerializer`), similarly for `XMLElementAttribute` and `serialize()` and `typeof(Comment)`, variable `txtComment` is undefined, and you've got a bunch of code outside of any method definition.

Comment: Also, you say "omitted other fields for clarity". Is there, by chance, a field or property named `commentDateSpecified` among those fields?

Comment: @Pavel I can't get the real code on here. I guess I was hoping for ideas on where else to look for issues on this so I would know which of the other 100k lines to put in here.

Comment: I found commentDateSpecified - should I add it?

Comment: Okay... So Pavel was right. I set that CommentDateSpecified boolean to true and it worked. Not sure why yet, but it worked.

Comment: @Matt, read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402199.aspx

Comment: @Stan R. That makes perfect sense. I am such a .Net idiot I didn't even realize DateTime was a value type. Would it make sense to set commentDateSpecified to true in my setter for commentDate (maybe in a wrapper class so I don't have to edit the generated code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavel's comment was the correct answer.

> Also, you say "omitted other fields
>   for clarity". Is there, by chance, a
>   field or property named
>   commentDateSpecified among those
>   fields?

Comment: Sadly it came about 15 months after I got the answer from Pavel in the comments to the original question.

Answer (score 14):

You need to set in order to be included in XML

```
 c.commentDateSpecified = true;
```

Comment: Out of everyone's answers yours is the only one that is actually correct and helped me.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt I agree, this should be the accepted answer. It has saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

The following works, you need to show the definition of comment:

```
public class comment
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public DateTime commentDate { get; set; }
}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(comment));
comment comment = new comment { text = "test", commentDate = DateTime.Now };
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, comment);
    stream.Position = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Don't know about *crucial* for testing. I have bitched about other people not having using statements on here as well, so I take your point.

Comment: I guess you're right they are not crucial for testing. Just saying that other people that come across this code to use as their own, might just copy and paste the code blindly.

Comment: Modified for the copy paste crowd.

Comment: I've thought a lot about inclusion of `using` statements as well, then I figure if paster can't decipher correct usings in C# then likely they also won't find the C# compiler or know how to set breakpoints to analyze snippets, and they'll also wonder why pasted code won't compile (missing a class), etc. etc...  A certain level of basic competency is required especially if we're already in the XML namespace here and dealing with serialization.

Comment: Not mention if you're copying and pasting code, and you don't understand it or test it, you deserve whatever memory leaks you get.

Comment: I see a lot of excuses for being lazy about writing correct code.  If it needs a using statement, include it for your own sake and as an exercise in good habits.